# Removing delimiters from a ListBox

Tags: c#, winforms

During the runtime I receive some entries into the ListBox (multiple items each line, see figure 1). I just want to keep the delimiters between two strings (see figure 2). All other delimiters should be removed. How can this be solved?  The code below removes all separators, but this is not exactly what I’m seeking for…

```
for (int i = 0; i < listBox2.Items.Count; i++)
{
  string item = listBox2.Items[i].ToString().Replace(" ", ",");
  listBox2.Items[i] = item.Trim();
}
```

[image]

Comment: `var item = string.Join(",", listBox2.Items[i].ToString().Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));`

Comment: Great!!! Thank you very much, "LarsTech" : )